# Can't vertically center content inside iron-pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I can't seem to be able to vertically center my content that resides within `iron-pages` (which in turns resides in a `paper-drawer-panel`). See example code below:

```
<paper-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel" responsive-width="1280px">

  <div class="nav" drawer>
    <!-- Nav Content -->
    <paper-menu attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
        <paper-item data-route="findParties">
          <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
          <span>Find Parties</span>
        </paper-item>
        <paper-item data-route="myParties">
          <iron-icon icon="icons:alarm-add"></iron-icon>
          <span>My Parties</span>
        </paper-item>
        <paper-item data-route="friends">
          <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
          <span>Friends</span>
        </paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
  </div>

  <paper-header-panel class="main" main mode="waterfall">

    <!-- Main Toolbar -->
    <paper-toolbar>
      <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    </paper-toolbar>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div>
      <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
        <div id="tempId" data-route="findParties">
           <party-list-item></party-list-item>
           <party-list-item></party-list-item>
        </div>

        <section data-route="myParties">
          My Parties
        </section>

        <section data-route="friends">
          My Friends
        </section>
      </iron-pages>
    </div>

  </paper-header-panel>

</paper-drawer-panel>
```

I've tried adding `class="layout vertical center-justified"` but it won't work. I also tried on some other places and create new divs and add the layout classes but it won't work either. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. There's no additional CSS that is being used other then what is generated by the `paper-elements.`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to *vertically* center the content in your iron-pages. In your current solution, the iron page does not fill up the available space. You can achieve that by adding a `fit` layout class. Then, using the classes that you have mentioned should work.

```
<iron-pages class="layout vertical center-justified fit">
```

**Update**

To center horizontally, specify horizontal in the class.

```
<iron-pages class="layout horizontal center-justified">
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention _how_ i wanted to center my items (edited my question). Yes I wanted to center them vertical. :/

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer. Just replace vertical with horizontal in the layout classes.

Comment: Thanks Maria for always answering my stupid Polymer-questions! Sorry once again for confusing you. I got confused about which centering is which. What I wanted was "vertical center". See link: http://plnkr.co/edit/xIARqr?p=preview
The reason it didn't center properly was I used _center-justified_ instead of just _center_.

Comment: No worries. Glad you found a solution to your problem.

Comment: And that plunker is really nice. I haven't been able to find much documentation on the layout classes.